# Nodejs instagram api post requesting authcode and it gives err 400

Tags: node.js, https, request

I am trying to send a post request to instagram to get an access token but when I send it I get err 400 which means bad syntax. Am I using bad syntax?

```
const request = require('request');
var formData = {
client_id: "theclientid",
client_secret: "thelcientsecret",
grant_type: "authorization_code",
redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/",
code: "thecode"
}
request.post({
    uri: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
    formData: formData,
    json: true
}, function(err, res, body) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
        var user = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(user);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print the response body you will see what the problem is.

```
{ error_type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 400,
  error_message: 'Invalid Client ID' }
```

Just try another `client_id`.